# How to get Data Uri from a file system image with javascript (localhost is not an option)

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, filesystems

I am writing a javascript app that will run offline on mozilla.I need to fetch an image from my file system and read it as datauri (without drag&drop or input,it must be done automatically by url).Localhost is not an option.An alternative would be to fetch this image from a url of a closed network but the app can't be on that network so i can't use ajax calls from the file system.Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers javascript implementation doesn't have access to local file system due security considerations. You will have to run some sort of web server to serve that file.